# Script not working while adding to the page but working if added to inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [this page](https://piovis.sauravsadangi.com/organisational-transformation/), I have added the below script:

```
<script>
    var secHightTop = $('.section-a').offset().top;
    var secHightTopp = $('.section-b').offset().top;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            var pageScroll = $(document).scrollTop() + 50;
            if (pageScroll >= secHightTop) {
                $('.hamburger .line').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
                $('header .top-logo img').css('margin-top', '-42px');
            } else {
                $('.hamburger .line').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
                $('header .top-logo img').css('margin-top', '0px');
            }
            if (pageScroll >= secHightTopp) {
                $('.hamburger .line').css('background-color', 'rgb(3, 17, 153)');
                $('header .top-logo img').css('margin-top', '0px');
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

It can be found just above the `</body>` tag of that page resulting the code is not working there.

But while I am adding that script in the inspector's console, it is working as expected.

Any particular reason for that? I am not sure how to get that working on the site itself.

Looking forward for any help.

Thank you.

Comment: There's 4 errors popping up by just loading the page. I'd start by fixing those.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the document to be ready (with `$(document).ready`) before defining `secHightTop` and `secHightTopp`?

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas Yes, I have tried that too, but not working

Comment: @icecub Those 4 errors are not related to this point. I'll remove them.